# Specified Orientation Not Displaying Correctly on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have a universal iOS (7.1+) app that I would like to only support portrait orientation for most views. I would like 1 view to autorotate.

The application is a navigation based application (i.e. the base view is a UINavigationViewController). In the project editor under Deployment Info I have checked portrait, landscape left and landscape right as the supported orientations.

I then restricted the autorotation of the app by implementing the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` method and the `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` in my base navigation controller. As I understand it, this will restrict the orientation in any view displayed by the navigation controller.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The view I would like to autorotate I present modally. In the view controller that I present modally I also set `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` and `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This solution works fine on iPhone! The one modal view rotates as expected and the other views inside the  However, the same view using the same code does not rotate on the iPad. I am confused as to why it works on the iPhone and not on the iPad. It seems to me that since it is the exact same view controller that it should rotate on both.

Comment: In project target setting's check Device->Device Orientation->iPad. It could  be different for device types.

Comment: @PavelGatilov Didn't think there would be separate orientation options in the Info.plist file. If you want to put that as an answer I will accept it!